# katex equations to image(png, jpg)

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, mathjax, katex

I am using katex in my web application to render Math equations. I need to convert the math equation into an image(png or jpg). I tried html2canvas.js, but it could not able to convert some symbols. Is there any front-end tools to convert math equations to image.?

Answer (score 2):

To generate an image client-side you'd want the formula rendered to a canvas then save that to a file. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/504) for render to canvas. A long while ago I had written an [implementation](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/pull/251). But it wasn't merged upstream and I haven't kept up with changes there. If you don't need recent KaTeX features you might still give that codebase of mine a try.

Otherwise there definitely is interest in getting a solution included. Ideally a solution would implement and then use an [intermediate representation](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/376) to be shared by all render backend.